# Is $\frac{1}{1+A}$ uniformly bounded process when $A$ is an increasing process with $A_0 = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

I read "Probability with Martingales" by David Williams.
I have trouble to understand the proof of 12.14.

Let $M$ be $\mathcal{L}^2$-martingale with $M_0 = 0$.
Of courese, $M^2$ has a doob decomposition: $M^2 = M^2_0 + N + A$. 
Here, $A$ is an increasing previsible process with $A_0 = 0$.

"Increasing process" means that 
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{P}(A_n \leq A_{n+1}, \forall n) = 1
\end{equation}
This means that $\mathbf{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega \mid A_n(\omega) \leq A_{n+1}(\omega), \forall n\}) = 1$.

My question is following:

"Is the process $\displaystyle{\left(\frac{1}{1+A}\right)}$ bounded?"

In other words, does the formula below holds?:

\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{1+A_n(\omega)}\right) \leq \left(\frac{1}{1+A_0(\omega)}\right) = 1 \quad (\forall \omega, \forall n)
\end{equation}

or I could say my question as:

"Is $A$ non-negative?"

I don't think it holds because $A$ is no more than $\textbf{almost surely}$ increasing. There should be a null set such that $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid A_n(\omega) > A_{n+1}(\omega), \exists n\}$. Therefore, if I take $\omega \in \{\omega \in \Omega \mid A_n(\omega) > A_{n+1}(\omega), \exists n\}$, it may be happen, for example, that
\begin{equation}
\left(\frac{1}{1+A_1(\omega)}\right) > \left(\frac{1}{1+A_0(\omega)}\right) = 1
\end{equation}
this contradicts to $\displaystyle{\left(\frac{1}{1+A}\right)}$ is bounded. So I cannot deduce "bounded".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally you are right. What Williams means is that the process is bounded **almost surely**. This is enough to prove the theorem anyway. (he proves that a limit exists almost surely, so it's not a problem to ignore a set of probability zero here)

Comment: Williams says in the third line in 12.14 that $W_n := ((1+A)^{-1} \bullet M)_n$ is a martingale. In order to prove it, I think he used the 10.7.(i) which is about martingale transformation. But here, we saw only $(1+A)^{-1}$ is $\textbf{bounded almost surely}$, so we should especially check $\mathbf{E}[|W_n|] < \infty$, right?

Comment: In the proof of 10.7.(i), he used "$C$ is uniformly bounded" for checking that $\mathbf{E}[|(C \bullet X)_n|] < \infty$. Therefore, we should check the integrability of $W_n$ of 12.14.

Comment: Not sure what is the problem. If you change the random variable at a set with probability zero you don't change the expectation. So you can assume it is bounded everywhere. (otherwise just change the values at a set with probability zero)